# How to make images fit to a screen no matter what the size is?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to make something like on the image below. 6 images, 3 images in 2 columns. I found this in an app. These 6 are just a preview of a video clip, not a real video clip. When I opened this .apk file I found that this guy placed all images in drawable folder. They are 285X213 resolution. I don't know how did he determine what resolution to use to make this fit to all the screens?? So, I was wondering, how to make these images fit to the screen no matter how big the screen is? I also want to use only drawable folder, and not to have to use all the sizes for each dpi.

[Screenshot (possibly NSFW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TUE8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at GridView: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

It will have some configs for columns and you can change on the code to show more or less depending on screen size.